# Lower bounding the number of children in branching process

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, computer-science

Suppose we have a recursive branching process where the number of children is given by $n p$ for parameters $n$ and (probability) $p$. Each child branches $n p$ children (once) and these children perform the same process. All samples are performed independently.

Let $Y_i$ be the number of generation-$i$ children. I believe the expectation of $Y_i$ is given by $(n p)^i$. While the expectation is easy to compute, I would like to have a lower bound on the probability of $Y_i$ being less than $(np)^i / 2$.

Chernoff bounds don't seem to be applicable here since there are dependencies between children on the same generation.
Is there any other concentration result that could be used instead?

Comment: You might want to explain "Each child branches np children". Please indicate the *distribution* of the number of children of each individual.

Comment: The number of children is a Bernoulli random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$.

Comment: OK (and I guess you mean *binomial*, not Bernoulli).

Comment: An easy lower bound (which does not go to zero when $i\to\infty$) is $P(Y_i\leqslant\frac12(np)^i)\geqslant P(Y_1=0)=(1-p)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer helps.

Firstly, note the definition of a probability generating function (PGF) , $f_X(s)$, of a random variable $X$:

$$f_X(s)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}P(X=i)s^i$$

So the PGF of $Y_i$, which we can call $f_i(s)$, can be evaluated at zero to get $P(Y_i=0)$.

For a binomial distributed random variable as per your parameters, the PGF of the offspring produced by a single individual takes the form 
$$f(s)=(ps+(1-p))^n $$

A standard result from Branching Processes is that $f_i(s)$ takes the form of the $i$ repeated compositions of the PGF of the offspring distribution:

$$f_i(s)=f(f_{i-1}(s))=f(f(f…f(s)…)$$

so long as the branching process is initiated by a single individual.

We can use these facts to calculate $P(Y_i=0)$, and use this as a lower bound. i.e.

$$P(Y_i<(np)^i/2)\geq P(Y_i=0)=f_i(0)$$

And $f_i(0)$ is calculated by recursion using:

$$f_i(0)=(pf_{i-1}(0)+(1-p))^n$$

with $f_1(0)$ being the bound that Did gave in his comment, i.e. $f_1(0)=(1-p)^n$. This bound should become quite good at large-$i$, since the branching process should either become very large, or approach extinction, so $P(Y_i<(np)^i/2)$ should approach the extinction probability, to which the expression just above should converge to.

Furthermore, note that $f_i(0)$ increases monotonically with increasing $i$ (can you see why?), so you can use the above method to calculate $f_j(0)$ for any $j\leq i$ to obtain another bound, if you don't want to calculate all the way to $f_i(0)$. In the case of $j=1$, this becomes Did's bound suggested in his comment.

EDIT: In the original answer, I suggested that the full PGF of $Y_i$ was available, and could be used to calculate a lower bound. This is indeed not the case, and so I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: To believe that because the generating functions satisfy the recursion $f_i=f\circ f_{i-1}$, the PGF of $Y_i$ would be "available" strikes me as verging on naiveness. Or, one should define precisely what is meant by "being available" here.

Comment: By 'available', I meant easily evaluated with a computer given $i$, which is why I stated at the beginning of my answer that I was mainly offering a solution from a computational perspective. I thought this might be useful to the OP, since he/she did include the computer-science tag with the question.

Comment: Won't you run pretty quickly into unsurpassable problems of computational accuracy?

Comment: I suppose that depends on exactly how you use the method. For large $i$, $P(Y_i<(np)^i/2)$ should be dominated by $P(Y_i=0)$, since the branching process should either explode or become extinct, so using $P(Y_i=0)$ as a lower bound might be sensible, and this is easily recovered using the method in my answer. I have edited my answer to explicitly show this.

Comment: So you seem to agree that PGFs are basically useless here.

Comment: I suggest that various PGFs evaluated at zero are easily calculated lower bounds for $P(Y_i<(np)^i/2)$, so I do not agree that the PGFs are useless. I hope I have made this clear in my edited answer.

Comment: The **value** of a PGF at 0 is simply the probability of 0, and to evaluate that, the full PGF (the **function**) is useless. This is fortunate since, once again, one cannot write down explicitely the PGF of a branching process (except for the first generations or for a few specific reproduction mechanisms).

Comment: The full PGF is not used, I agree. But PGFs are used to derive the recursive relationship of the extinction probability from one generation to the next. How do you propose to calculate the extinction probability by generation $i$ without using PGFs?

Comment: To sum up, the full PGF is neither "available" nor used. This was my point from the start so everything is cool (the rest of your comment is not related to what I actually wrote).

Comment: I now see your point. Indeed, full PGFs are not available, nor used. But PGFs are useful in that they give rise to useful recursive relationships. I now edit my answer to be consistent with this.

Answer (score 0):

I state an asymptotic result for $i\to \infty$, but cannot give a result for finite $i$.

Note that for $m= np$ it is true that $(m^{-i}Y_i)_{i\geq 1}$ is a nonnegative martingale. Nonnegative martingales converge almost surely, say to the random variable $W$. This includes saying that as $i\to \infty$:
$$ P(m^{-i} Y_i < \frac{1}{2}) \to P(W < \frac{1}{2}) .$$

This is classical theory on branching processes; see Section I.8 in Harris' book on branching processes or page 33 of http://www.math.ubc.ca/~db5d/SummerSchool09/lectures-dd/lecture2-3.pdf which contains some ideas and references for the convergence result.

Basically, in the supercritical (i.e. $m>1$) case $P(W < 1/2) \in (0,1)$ and in the other cases $P(W<1/2) = 1$. The last fact comes from the extinction of the almost sure extinction of the process $(Y_i)_{i\geq 1}$ when $m\leq 1$.